# How ignore empty response in ruby view loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

as i'm new to ruby and rails in general i would have a short question cause i'm stuck at a minor issue.

I'm calling a content API from my controller and looping thru the response in the view directly. The main problem is: If one of the objects, has an empty value which i'm calling..it breaks the view.

Question would be how can i scip the elements which are emtpy...in example if post["heroimage"]["url"] is empty?

Example view:

```
<div class="gallery">
<% @blog.each do |post| %>
  <a target="_blank" href="blog/<%= post["id"] %>">
    <img src="<%= @host + post["heroimage"]["url"]%>" alt="" width="600" height="400">
  </a>
  <div class="desc"><%= post['description'] %></div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: `post["heroimage"]` is nil or `post["heroimage"]["url"]` is blank?

Comment: Do you really want to skip this or just not show an image or maybe use a default image?

Comment: I just want to "not show" the image. Next step will be to use a static placeholder if value empty.

By now it breaks and says `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: In that case you can either wrap the anchor tag in an if statement e.g. `<% if post['heroimage'] %>` or you can have a sourceless image, to remind you to fix this, by using what is called safe navigation e.g. `post['heroimage']&.[]('url')` to resolve this with a default image I would recommend `post['heroimage'].fetch('url','default location')`

Comment: Thanks, i ended up with the ´<% if post['heroimage'] %>´ solution..as all this others didnt work out for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing Rails or Rails views specific about your question. What you're trying to do is skip elements in an `each` loop in Ruby, and the answer is, `next`

```
somethings.each do |thing|
  next if thing.nil?

  # .. does not get called if thing is nil
end
```

Comment: yep, `next` is one way to go. Alternatively, the controller could pre-process the data and discard "empty" rows, so the view doesn't have to deal with them.

Comment: Thanks, i see that my question is/was not clear enough. I'm able to skip the whole object, but i want to only skip empty values (or even better to use placeholders instead).

So i.e. if image is missing, title should be rendered anyway.

Comment: then you have to check these values individually, there is no auto-magic solution for this

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from the question and your comments you can use,

```rb
post.dig("heroimage", "url")
```

[here](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/dig) is the link to dig method documentation. If you want to skip the image in case of empty `url` you can do something like this

```rb
<div class="gallery">
<% @blog.each do |post| %>
  <a target="_blank" href="blog/<%= post["id"] %>">
    <% if post.dig("heroimage", "url") %>
      <img src="<%= @host + post["heroimage"]["url"]%>" alt="" width="600" height="400">
    <% end %>
  </a>
  <div class="desc"><%= post['description'] %></div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

This will still show the title even if the image URL is empty.